# How to express a number of non-matching items in ordered subsets as math formula

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**The Question**

Given:

- $\mathbf O$ is a set of objects(items?) $\mathbf o$ with size $n$, $\mathbf O=\{o_1,o_2,...,o_n\}$
- Each of $\mathbf o_i$ is an m-tuple, where $\mathbf o_i=(o_{i1},o_{i2},...,o_{im})$.
- It is allowed for $\mathbf o_i$ to have "empty" items.

**What i need**:

- Iterate across all items in $\mathbf O$ set
- Match items one to another ($\mathbf o_i$ and $\mathbf o_j$, excluding $i=j$) in the following way:
- If $\mathbf o_{in}=\mathbf o_{jn}$ (except for $nil=nil$), then it is $+1$ to result
- if $\mathbf o_{in}\neq\mathbf o_{jn}$, then $0$
- **Express result as a formula something like $\sum_1^n\sum_1^m o_{nm}=o_{nm}$ $\leftarrow$ that is the goal.**

**Example for a bit of context**

We have $\mathbf O=\{(1,2,nil,4),(nil,2,nil,5)\}$. $n=2$ and $m=4$

It means that we have two objects:

- $\mathbf o_1=(1,2,nil,4)$
- $\mathbf o_2=(nil,2,nil,5)$

Lets compare them:

- $\mathbf o_{11}=1$ and $\mathbf o_{21}=nil$, then $1\neq nil$, so $total=0$
- $\mathbf o_{12}=2$ and $\mathbf o_{22}=2$, then $2=2$, so $total=1$
- $\mathbf o_{13}=nil$ and $\mathbf o_{23}=nil$, then $nil=nil$, but this is an exception, so $total=1$ was not changed
- $\mathbf o_{14}=4$ and $\mathbf o_{24}=5$, then $4\neq 5$, so $total=1$ (not changed)

Comment: Are you sure that the $o_i$ are sets and not **ordered** $m$-tuples?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, I am not sure. I AM really NOT into math stuff.

I've checked the wiki and your comment seems legit. Unfortunately I dont know how  to update my question.

If instead of: `Each of oi is a set of same known size of m across all items in oi, where oi={oi1,oi2,...,oim}.`

I will write `Each of oi is m-tuple, where oi={oi1,oi2,...,oim}.`

Would it be correct statement?

Comment: For $m$-tuples, use regular parentheses instead of curly brackets.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, i've updated a question according to your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let r$_{jk}$ be the result of comparing o$_j$ with o$_k$.
The result of all comparisons is
$\sum_{j=1,n-1}\sum_{k=j+1,n} r_{jk}.$

If all the objects are unique, then O can be a set.
If not, then O has to be a finite sequence or n-tuple.
Such is recommended as the objects are numbered.

Comment: @willam-elliot , those objects are EXPECTED to be unique, while it is possible for them to have same values on same positions. For example $(1,2), (1,2)$ - This is possible.